# Stationarity of time series with KPSS test

Tags: time-series, stationarity, kpss-test

I have dataset with size 4630 and I used KPSS test to check if it is stationary or not. I get on this output, Is that mean the value of p_value is not correct? or how can test large values with kpss test?

```
InterpolationWarning: The test statistic is outside of the range of p-values available in the
look-up table. The actual p-value is smaller than the p-value returned.

  warnings.warn(
KPSS Statistic: 1.500480764853612
p-value: 0.01
Critial Values:
   10% : 0.347
   5% : 0.463
   2.5% : 0.574
   1% : 0.739
Result: The series is not stationary
```

Comment: The warning seems clear: the p-value of the test is less than 1%. It doesn't know how much less, but since most people don't usually require such low levels anyway, in practice it shouldn't matter: the test is rejected. Do you *really* need to know the p-value?

Comment: In this case, is the test results considered correct? Can I use it as a correct result? Is there a way to  know the exact value of p-value ?

Comment: Whether the test results are considered "correct" is completely independent of the results presented here. We can't know whether the results are correct based on what you've shown. There's not anything intrinsically wrong with this result, and in fact this function will never return an "exact" p-value: the critical values shown are based on Monte Carlo experiments and quoted from the original KPSS paper, and when the p-value would fall within the table, it is interpolated from it, so it's always an estimate.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, As long as the estimated value of the p-value is less than 0,01 and 0.01<0.05, so it is not stationary. Is that correct?

Comment: If the data is large, for example 5000, are these tests be not accurate?

Comment: closely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/581467/testing-by-using-kpss/581577#581577